# Simple if-else php injection

Tags: php, code-injection, if-statement

Simple question.
I try to make simple page that use one key. 
Is this safe?

```
$a = $_POST["a"];
$a = htmlspecialchars($a);

if($a=="1234") {
printf($a);   
}else {
header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: My first question, so sorry about lack of information. Password will not be 1234, more like "fdgQe43aQf". And this wont be only protection or lock. Thanks evryone! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a terrible way to lock an application, but you are not opening yourself up to any injection attacks with that code

Answer (score 1):

Well since you will print `$a` only if it's `1234` then it can do no harm. Plus you are not using `$a` in any SQL statement so it's safe.

Comment: I would also check if they're identical (===).

Answer (score 0):

The only "injection" you need to worry about is if you used that in an `eval` statement or an SQL query.

Otherwise, it doesn't matter.  You don't need the `htmlspecialchars` here.

Comment: So you cant break if-statment?

Comment: @user1532559: Nope! :-D  The only way it could "break" is if `$_POST['a']` wasn't set.